# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/lexer/Encoding

Tags: java, cucumber

Hi I have an error when I run my feature files in eclipse.

I do have the latest cucumber jar also still no luck. Any ideas on how to resolve? I've also pointed the

Here's my code:

```
package Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format = {"pretty", "json:target/"},
        features = {"src/cucumber/"}
        )
public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

Here's my feature file.

```
    Feature: My Feature
  Scenario: Title of your scenario
    Given This is my first test
    And This is my second test
    Then This is my final test
```

Here's the error I'm recieving.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/lexer/Encoding
    at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.read(FeatureBuilder.java:154)
    at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:115)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromFeaturePath(CucumberFeature.java:104)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:54)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:235)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:110)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.lexer.Encoding
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790155/cant-execute-feature-in-cucumber-jvm) question.

Comment: It does appear as though it is, still unresolved either way.

Comment: Did you try the answer with 2 upvotes on that post?

Comment: I have chopped and changed the core and gherkin files but still get the same issue. On the video I'm following one of the solutions is to use the latest cucumber jar file which I am using. I have all the latest jars.

Comment: Please share your build script as well. There is obviously something missing.

Comment: You seem to be testing how to setup Cucumber for Java. Have you considered cloning the Java getting started skeleton provided from Cucumber? It may be easier for you to get started with. It is available here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Answer (score 1):

Try Cucumber-core , cucumber-java and cucumber-junit jars as 1.2.0 and gherkin version 2.12.2 , it worked for me with this combination after several fails.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I've gone through my Jar files again and noticed the Gherkin jar was a fair way out so I did actually find the latest one used that instead and it now runs correctly. Cheers for you help though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution for the problem you guys are encountering. I downloaded an old version of gherkin (2.9.3), while the lastest is 2.12.2. Therefore please download gherkin 2.12.2 and run.

Comment: No, don't delete the question - it's useful for others such as me with the same problem. (It doesn't solve my problem, but it was something I needed to eliminate.)

Answer (score 0):

Updating your pom .xml file with latest version of gherkin file sloves the issue . included the dependency below but always look for latest gherkin file

```
         <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
         </dependency>
```